# Display results of a user search, using up to three inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Summary:** I have a search bar with 3 inputs: NAME, DATE OF BIRTH, AND SSN. Following is a `<ul>` containing the corresponding 3 columns and data.

[image: Three Input Search Bar]

*New Searchbar HTML:*

```
<div class="adv-searchbar">
        <div class="adv-searchbar__wrapper">
            <span>Search people in database. . .</span>
            <div class="adv-searchbar__wrapper__search-box">
                <span class="search__column-1"><img src="/img/person-name.png" class="search__input-ico"/><input type="text" class="search__input" id="search__adv-input-1" placeholder="John Adam Smith"></span>
                <span class="search__column-2"><input type="date" class="search__input" id="adv-input-2" placeholder="MM / DD / YY"></span>
                <span class="search__column-3"><img src="/img/person-ssn.png" class="search__input-ico"/><input type="text" class="search__input" id="search__adv-input-3" placeholder="### - ## - ####"></span>
                <button type="submit" class="advSearchBtn"><img src="/img/search_white.png"/></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Table HTML (with only one item):

```
            <div class="table_body">
            <ul>
                <li><div class="item">
                    <div class="column-1">
                        <span>Luke Isitt</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column-2">
                        <span>10 / 01 / 1998</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column-3">
                        <span>123-45-6789</span>
                    </div>
                </div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Previously I had created this with a search bar that took 1 input and activated on keyup, which worked successfully. The Js for the *1 input* (NAME, DATE OF BIRTH, OR SSN) function looks like this:

*Old Search Bar HTML*

```
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="search_box">
                <img src="~/asset/img/search_grey.png" class="search-icon">
                <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="Type to search...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Old Search Bar Function*

```
search_input.on("keyup", function (e) {
   let search_item = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
   let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.table_body .item');

   inputs.forEach(function (item) {
       if (item.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_item) != -1) {
           item.closest('li').style.display = "block";
       } else { item.closest('li').style.display = "none"; }
   });
});
```

Now the database for this data is much larger, so I've added optional inputs that I only want to execute on button click or when the user presses enter. The user can input a NAME, a NAME + DATE OF BIRTH, a NAME + DATE OF BIRTH + SSN, or any other combination.

**EFFORT:** I created a simple function that outputs the 3 input values to the console. From this, I know that Date of Birth (DoB) *value* will be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD (10/01/1998 becomes 1998-10-01). By limiting the maximum year to 4 integers, I have reformatted the string to meet my expectations (MM/DD/YYYY).

Now I'm trying to create a variable that holds the user input value(s), and create a new .forEach() statement that loops through the '.data_table .item', but this is where I am stuck. I can still get the results for 1 input, but not all 3. Unfortunately most available search bar resources are for 1 input.

```
   function searchEntries() {
      let values = [...$('.search__input')]; // works
      console.log(values[0].value, values[1].value, values[2].value); // works
      console.log(values);

      // unsure how to progress
   }
```

Console log for input (LUKE ISITT, 10/01/1998/ 123-45-6789):

```
LUKE ISITT 1998-10-01 123-45-6789
index.js:39 (3) [input#search__adv-input-1.search__input, input#adv-input-2.search__input, input#search__adv-input-3.search__input]
```

Comment: So you have issue with the "New Search Bar Function"? It's not included in your post, only the "Old" one

Comment: Yes, I didn't include the newest function since I didn't get very far before I got stuck, but I just updated it. @CalebTaylor

Comment: Just a side note:  It's insecure to display SSNs.  And hopefully you're storing them in a secure manner and not just as plain text...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where if any of the 3 inputs (name, date, or ssn) matches with the columns, it will be displayed while others are filtered out.

Here's a filter function that can be invoked by keyup on all search inputs or when a submit button is clicked.

```js
function searchEntries() {
  let name = $("#search__adv-input-1").value.toLowerCase();
  let date = $("#search__adv-input-2").value;
  let ssn = $("#search__adv-input-3").value; // not secure to display SSNs

  return { name, date, ssn };
}

function filterItems() {
  let { name, date, ssn } = searchEntries(); // returns an object, then destructuring it
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".table_body .item");

  inputs.forEach(function (item) {
    let columnName = item.querySelector(".column-1").textContent.toLowerCase();
    let columnDate = item.querySelector(".column-2").textContent;
    let columnSSN = item.querySelector(".column-3").textContent; // not secure to display SSNs

    if (
      columnName.indexOf(name) !== -1 ||
      columnDate.indexOf(date) !== -1 ||
      columnSSN.indexOf(ssn) !== -1
    ) {
      item.closest("li").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      item.closest("li").style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}

search_input_name.on("keyup", filterItems);
search_input_date.on("keyup", filterItems);
search_input_ssn.on("keyup", filterItems);
// or
searchBtn.on("click", filterItems);
```